# Web scrape subtitles from opensubtitles.org in R

Tags: r, web-scraping

I'm new to web scraping, and I'm currently trying to download subtitle files for over 100,000 films for a research project. Each film has a unique IMDb ID (i.e., the ID for Inception is `1375666`). I have a list in R containing the 102524 IDs, and I want to download the corresponding subtitles from opensubtitles.org.

Each film has its own page on the site, for example, Inception has:

https://www.opensubtitles.org/en/search/sublanguageid-eng/imdbid-1375666

The link to download the subtitles is obtained by clicking on the first link in the table called "Movie name", which takes you to a new page, then clicking the "Download button" on that page.

I'm using `rvest` to scrape the pages, and I've written this code:

```
for(i in 1:102524) {
  subtitle.url = paste0("https://www.opensubtitles.org/en/search/sublanguageid-eng/imdbid-", movie.ids[i])

  read_html(subtitle.url) %>%
    html_nodes(".head+ .expandable .bnone")
  # Not sure where to go from here
}
```

Any help on how to do this will be greatly appreciated.

EDIT: I know I'm asking something pretty complicated, but any pointers on where to start would be great.

Comment: where is the code that does a time pause to not overload the site? Did you even read http://trac.opensubtitles.org/projects/opensubtitles/wiki/DevReadFirst first (like it says to on the site)?

Comment: @hrbrmstr, see the answer below where a time delay is implemented. (I was going to add a time delay, as soon as I figured out how to do what I was trying to do).

Comment: GGamba is a decent chap (note my comment there). your second question alluded to you having designs to deliberately circumvent site restrictions b/c you believed you were entitled to. I will make no assumptions or comments about my belief about your promise to have added a delay in your final project.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Following the link and the download button, we can see that the actual subtitle file is downloaded from `https://www.opensubtitles.org/en/download/vrf-108d030f/sub/6961922` (for you example). I found out this inspecting the `Network` tab in Mozilla's `Developer Tools` while doing a download.

We can download directly from that address using:

```
    download.file('https://www.opensubtitles.org/en/download/vrf-108d030f/sub/6961922', 
              destfile = 'subtitle-6961922.zip')
```

The base url (`https://www.opensubtitles.org/en/download/vrf-108d030f/sub/`) is fixed for all the downloads as far as I can see, so we only need the site's id.

The id is found within the search page doing:

```
id <- read_html(subtitle.url) %>%
    html_node('.bnone') %>% 
    html_attr('href') %>% 
    stringr::str_extract('\\d+')
```

So, putting it all together:

```
search_url <- 'https://www.opensubtitles.org/en/search/sublanguageid-eng/imdbid-'
download_url <- 'https://www.opensubtitles.org/en/download/vrf-108d030f/sub/'

for(i in 1:102524) {
    subtitle.url = paste0(search_url, movie.ids[i])

    id <- read_html(subtitle.url) %>%
        html_node('.bnone') %>% 
        html_attr('href') %>% 
        stringr::str_extract('\\d+')

    download.file(paste0(download_url, id), 
                  destfile = paste0('subtitle-', movie.ids[i], '.zip'))

    # Wait somwhere between 1 and 4 second before next download
    # as courtesy to the site
    Sys.sleep(runif(1, 1, 4))
}
```

Keep in mind this will take a long time!

Comment: That's amazing! Thank you :)